# PyGame Mouse Cursor Center of Player Image

Tags: python, image, pygame, mouse

Have just started using PyGame in Python. I have managed to set the player_image to follow the mouse cursor, but the image is not centred over the position of the cursor. The cursor always seems to be in the top left corner of the image. Could anyone help me with getting it so that the image is over the centre of the mouse cursor? I can then turn the mouse cursor off and the image track the movement correctly.

I have the below section of code so far, with a background set in the pygame window:

```
player_image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png").convert_alpha()
player_image_rect = player_image.get_rect()  
player_image_rect.centerx = player_image.get_rect().centerx
player_image_rect.centery = player_image.get_rect().centery
screen.blit(player_image, player_image_rect)
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
```

Thanks

Full code (I've slowly been adding in mixture of features):

```
import sys
import pygame
import random


black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

# Initialise PyGame
pygame.init()

#Set screen dimensions and title
width = 802
height = 585
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Attack Game v1")

#Load and set up graphics position
background_position = [0, 0]
background_image = pygame.image.load("solarsystem.jpg").convert()


#Set game title on screen text
basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 68)
text = basicfont.render('Space Attack', True, white).convert_alpha()
text_rect = text.get_rect()
#textrect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
#textrect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery

#Set player mouse control image
player_image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png").convert_alpha()
player_image_rect = player_image.get_rect()
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
player_image_rect.center = pos
#player_image_rect.centerx = player_image.get_rect().centerx
#player_image_rect.centery = player_image.get_rect().centery
screen.blit(player_image, player_image_rect.center)
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

#Load star
star_image = pygame.image.load("star.png").convert_alpha()
screen.blit(star_image, (random.randint(0,width),random.randint(0,height)) )
#star_image_rect = star_image.get_rect()
pygame.display.flip()

#######################################################
done = False

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        screen.blit(star_image, (random.randint(0,width),random.randint(0,height)))

    class ball:
        def __init__(self,X,Y):
            self.velocity = [1,1]
            self.ball_image = pygame.image.load('alien.png').convert()
            self.ball_image.set_colorkey(black)
            self.ball_boundary = self.ball_image.get_rect (center=(X,Y))
            self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
            #self.sound = pygame.mixer.Sound ('Collide.wav')


    if __name__ =='__main__':

        num_balls = 5
        ball_list = []

        for i in range(num_balls):
            ball_list.append( ball(random.randint(0, width),random.randint(0, height)) )
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit(0)

            for ball in ball_list:
                if ball.ball_boundary.left < 0 or ball.ball_boundary.right > width:
                    #ball.sound.play()
                    ball.velocity[0] = -1 * ball.velocity[0]
                if ball.ball_boundary.top < 0 or ball.ball_boundary.bottom > height:
                    #ball.sound.play()
                    ball.velocity[1] = -1 * ball.velocity[1]

                ball.ball_boundary = ball.ball_boundary.move (ball.velocity)
                screen.blit (ball.ball_image, ball.ball_boundary)

            player_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x = player_position[0]
            y = player_position[1]
            pygame.display.flip()

            screen.blit(background_image, background_position)
            screen.blit(text, text_rect)

            screen.blit(player_image, [x,y])

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: how wide in pixels is your image?

Comment: I know the centre coordinates are 48 and 47.

Comment: Are you sure your gameloop keeps running? Sloth's code definitely works.

Comment: I've just added my full code including the loop. It runs the loop as the spaceships (what started off as balls) are all moving. Any thoughts where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `center` of your `Rect` to the mouse position, like

```
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
player_image_rect.center = pos
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still hasn't done it. I inserted that before the screen blit and no change.